# if $N$ and $H$ are subgroups of $G$ such that $N \trianglelefteq G$ and $N \leq H \leq G$, then $N \trianglelefteq H$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove: Show that if $N$ and $H$ are subgroups of $G$ such that $N \trianglelefteq G$ and $N \leq H \leq G$, then $N \trianglelefteq H$.

My attempt: Use that $N \trianglelefteq G$ to say that the left and right cosets are equal ($aN=Na$ for all $a \in G$). And, since $H \leq G$ then any element in $H$ is one of the elements from $G$. So, a subset of the $a$ elements for which the earlier result was true ($aN=Na$ for all $a \in G$) must also be true so that $aN=Na$ for all $a \in H$.

Is this correct (...and is it rigorous enough? I kind of feel like I'm writing "it's obvious" but while just using more words).

Comment: You are right, and it's really obvious like you said!

Comment: Oh ok. Haha fantastic, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. Here is an alternative argument: normal subgroups are precisely those as arise as kernels of homomorphisms. But $N$ is exactly the kernel of the composition $H \hookrightarrow G \twoheadrightarrow G/N$ of the inclusion of $H$ into $G$ with the canonical projection of $G$ onto $G/N$.